# Displays turn on at midnight (00:00)

Tags: 20.04

Every day at midnight my displays goes from blank to on. Always at exactly 00:00. I'm not sure what is causing this. I have tried "Do Not Disturb" for notifications.

I'm using multiple displays if that is relevant.

How can I turn this off?

Comment: I have also disabled "Lock Screen Notifications".

Comment: Ubuntu release/version?